# China phone new, touch not working

Tags: adb, touch

Maybe anybody can help me. I got a brand new china phone (xgody) with no working touch. As it was a present to the Dominican Republic, back shipping was not an option.
As the situation goes a little pressured now in Virus times, I do not have the money to buy a new phone and I need at least an emergency phone.
The screen looks perfectly fine, the buttons work, just the touch does not do anything. (I reached the google account password when it happened, after that no reaction on touch) For any reason, the USB connect is on charging only.

1. otg does not work on that phone
2. the only solution non-otg may be to enable USB debugging with adb command, but all solutions use nearly the same word by word and something is missing. I never get the command window from adb to write something. all articles say to hold power button, volume up/down + home button. My home button is touch, for that I cant do this.
3. Yes, I can reach factory mode on the phone, but there are only worthless tests, clear eMMC, version and reboot.

Anybody maybe can help me please.
thx so much in advance